# Can we make CloudBees SDK in Windows sase sensitive?

Tags: cloudbees

We recently began using the CloudBees SDK to develop and test locally.  We then use the CloudBees command "bees deploy" to send our app to the cloud.

We run the SDK in Windows and the app deploys (we believe) in Linux.  Linux is case sensitive and Windows is not.

Is there a way to enforce case sensitivity within the CloudBees SDK?  We really need to be developing within the same "environment" as it were, and so far this is not the case.

Comment: Case-sensitive in what respect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDK can't make windows case sensitive. System is not, there is no other option that running on a case-sensitive OS, maybe using virtualbox.

Comment: Okay, thanks very much.  I wasn't sure if there was some way to enable case-sensitivity within TomCat since that is actually interpreting and serving the code.